# how my program attaches a running program? like gdb does. in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

I'm wondering how gdb attaches a running program in linux(*nix)?

I have windows "hook" programming experience. 
On windows, I can register a "Hook" to some events of a program(or any program), and when the event occurs(such as mouse click), OS injects my hook-dll into that program's process space and invokes my callback function. Then my program attaches a running program and gets access to the attached program's data and functions.

How does linux do? Does it similar to Windows?

Thank you, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be through the [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)() function.  Although, I've never played around with it.

Comment: ptrace() manual says that: "The ptrace() system call provides a means by which a **parent process** may observe and control the execution of another process, ..." which means my program has to be the parent of a program which I want to attach? How can I do it?

Comment: @iCoder: Tracing a child process is the easier way, but you can also trace an unrelated process owned by the same user using `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0)`